# How do I apply a function to a subset of each of several columns?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I had a `data.table` like this:

```
> test.dt = data.table(alice = 2:-1, bob = -1:2, claire = 0:-1, x = 2:5)
> test.dt
   alice bob claire x
1:     2  -1      0 2
2:     1   0     -1 3
3:     0   1      0 4
4:    -1   2     -1 5
```

but in general there are many more names than just "alice", "bob", and "claire" and they are stored in a vector

```
names = c("alice", "bob", "claire")
```

Unlike "alice", "bob", or "claire", the column "x" is a special column not in `names`.

Suppose I had a function `f(name, x)` taking vector inputs. I would like to do the following: within each column whose name is in `names`, replace (in place) all positive values with `f(name, x)` and leave the other values unchanged.

This seems like a simple enough task which could be done as follows in pandas (renaming `test.dt` to `df`):

```
for name in names:
    df.loc[df[name] > 0, name] = f(df.loc[df[name] > 0, name],
                                   df.loc[df[name] > 0, "x"])
```

but I cannot figure out how to do it in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) it could be a good choice (as it is in this case) to use a for loop as follows (using the same function as @Ronak):

```
for (n in nms) {
  test.dt[get(n) > 0, (n) := f(get(n), 2L)]
}
```

which gives:

> ```
> > test.dt
>    alice bob claire x
> 1:     4  -1      0 2
> 2:     2   0     -1 3
> 3:     0   2      0 4
> 4:    -1   4     -1 5
> ```

Note: try to avoid to give object the same name as a function; hence I renamed the `names` vector to `nms`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function

```
f <- function(x, n) x * n
```

We can use `.SDcols` to specify column by names

```
library(data.table)
test.dt[, (names) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(x > 0, f(x, 2), x)), .SDcols = names]

test.dt
#   alice bob claire x
#1:     4  -1      0 2
#2:     2   0     -1 3
#3:     0   2      0 4
#4:    -1   4     -1 5
```